# Then de PromiseAll return undefined

Tags: laravel, vue.js, promesas, async-await

Estoy desarrollando una aplicacion con Vue y Laravel que en uno de los componentes estoy utilizando un `Promise.All()`, el problema que estoy teniendo es que el `then` del `Promise.All()` me devuelve un arreglo y dentro de este arreglo dos `undenfined`.

Este es mi código:

```
export default {
        name: 'Create_vin',
        components: {Select2},
        data(){
            return {
                select_equipment_code: '',
                select_place_production: '',
                equipment_codes: [],
                place_production: [],
                vin_code: 'Numero X',
                errormsg: ''
            }
        },
        created(){

            Promise.all([this.loadEquipmentCode(), this.loadPlaceProduction()])
                .then(values => {                        

                    console.log(this.equipment_codes)
                console.log(this.place_production)

                return console.log(values)
                    
                }).catch(error => {

                    console.log(error.response.data.message)
                    this.errormsg = error.response.data.message;
                });
        },
        methods: {
            async  loadEquipmentCode(){

                await this.axios.get('api/equipmentCodes').then((resp) => {

                    const first_data = [{
                        id: '0',
                        text: 'Select the equipment code...'
                    }];

                    return [...first_data, ...resp.data.data];

               });
            },

            async loadPlaceProduction(){
                await this.axios.get('api/placeProductions').then((resp) => {
                    const first_data = [{
                        id: '0',
                        text: 'Select the place of production ...'
                    }];

                    return [...first_data, ...resp.data.data];

                });
            },
            myChangeEvent(val){
                console.log(val)
            },
            myChangeEventPlace(val){
                console.log(val)
            }
        },
        
    }
```

Comment: Esto: `return console.log(values)` siempre será `undefined`. Porqué retornar un `console.log`. No será que quieres retornar los valores? Algo como `return values`?. Por otro lado, dónde pretendes consumir el resultado de esa Promesa? No queda claro el propósito de la misma ni cómo vas a usarla.